The expression "в один уповод"
In the novel Детство Люверс by Boris Pasternak, someone replies as follows to Женечка (a little girl), who asked whether some woman, who gave birth some days ago, is again pregnant:

— Ми-ил!.. Дай отдохнуть. Не завсе ж ей, Женечка, в один уповод...

"Дай отдохнуть." is clear to me but I don't understand the next sentence (even if, with the context, I can guess more or less the global meaning): I found that "завсе" means "всегда" and "ей" is probably referring to the woman who just gave birth but I don't understand "в один уповод" ("уповод" on gramota.ru and "уповод" on Викисловарь don't provide any result).

I like Multitran (https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?s=%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4&l1=2&l2=1). It is the go-to reference used by Russian translators themselves. Завсе is dialectal, meaning "always, continually". В один уповод means--or can mean--"in a single shift, in a single daily stint", also dialectal. Уповод is also found in Dahl's dictionary (the famous pre-revolutionary dictionary in the old script). See https://azbyka.ru/otechnik/Spravochniki/tolkovyj-slovar-zhivogo-velikorusskogo-jazyka-v-i-dalja-bukva-u/636 (where it states this word means a time period of 2-4 hours, so a different nuance of meaning from Multitran).
Do these meanings make any sense in the wider context? I'm not a native speaker, and so we really need a native speaker to jump in when things are this dialectal... so, just trying to help anyway.
Maybe:

She needs to get some rest (you have said the context is rest from
being pregnant). This shouldn't always be happening to her, and in
such a short space of time...

Stress: за́все, у́повод (the latter stress indicated in https://sanstv.ru/dict/%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Thanks for the reference to Dahl's dictionary. I have never heard this word before. As well as "не завсе ж". It sounds like something between "не всё ж" (not all the time, not forever, like in не всё коту масленица) and "завсегда" (at any moment, always), which I didn't see used with negation.

I accept this answer, but Quassnoi's answer provides some complementary information. I should have better used Google before asking my question, I just found this link: https://www.booksite.ru/fulltext/zolotye/text.pdf (the place of the dialogue is Ekaterinburg, which is far away from Vologda, but I suppose that the meaning is the same in the two regions), where we have this meaning: "Сразу, быстро, мгновенно." (it seems to me that pompey1969's translation is closer to this meaning than @Quassnoi 's translation).

Уповод or уповодь (cognate to повод "rein") is an amount of work (or a length of way) that a horse can do without taking a rest.
By extension, в один уповод means "in one sitting, at one go".

Indeed we will use в один присест today.

The meaning of “зАвсе” (завсегда — нареч. обстоят. времени разг.-сниж.
в любое время; всегда.) is “always”; “Уповод” here means “срок” ((2) (промежуток времени) period, term.) now completely obsolete.
